# Display duplicate xml element values in rows in tsql

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

```
declare @doc xml; 

SET @doc =  
'<Cars>
<Car>
  <Details>
    <Name>corolla</Name>
    <Company>Toyota</Company>
  </Details>
  <Parts>
    <Part>steering</Part>
    <Part>Exhauster</Part>
    <Part>doors</Part>
    <Part>Breaks</Part>
  </Parts>
</Car>
<Car>
  <Details>
    <Name>Pilot</Name>
    <Company>Honda</Company>
  </Details>
  <Parts>
    <Part>steering</Part>
    <Part>Exhauster</Part>
    <Part>doors</Part>
  </Parts>
</Car>
</Cars>';
```

With the below query, getting below results

```
SELECT 
   data.col.query('Details/Name/./text()') as Name, 
   data.col.query('Details/Company/./text  ()') as Company, 
   data.col.query('Parts/Part/./text()') as Parts 
FROM 
   @doc.nodes('(Cars/Car)') AS data(col)

 Name       Company         Parts
----------------------------------------------
corolla Toyota  steeringExhausterdoorsBreaks
Pilot   Honda   steeringExhausterdoors
```

Expecting the following result

```
  Name       Company         Parts
-----------------------------------
  Corolla     Toyota        steering
  Corolla     Toyota        Exhauster
  Corolla     Toyota        doors
  Corolla     Toyota        Breaks
  Pilot       Honda         steering
  Pilot       Honda         Exhauster
  Pilot       Honda         doors
```

Tried few examples but didn't succeed. Please suggest where I'm missing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
   data.col.value('(Details/Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Name, 
   data.col.value('(Details/Company)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Company, 
   Data2.PartCol.value('.', 'varchar(40)') as Parts 
FROM 
   @doc.nodes('(Cars/Car)') AS data(col)
CROSS APPLY
    DATA.col.nodes('Parts/Part') AS Data2(PartCol)
```

Since the `<Parts>/<Part>` sub elements are again a **list of elements** inside the `<Car>` node, you need to use another `.nodes()` call with a `CROSS APPLY` operator to get all these subnodes.

Also - please use the `.value()` function instead of `.query()` to get individual values!

Comment: Excellent!! it worked. Appreciate your immediate response. Thanks